# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function for all functions

Tags: php, fatal-error, contact-form, redeclare

I think I have had a bug with a contact form which has been working for the last 2 months and now all of a sudden is says:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function (previously declared in...)

I have tried turning off the functions one by one but it just gives same error for next function down. My code is pretty standard. but, here it is `(this is the beginning of the function. The code is long)`
        //Functions

```
  function e($value)
  {
     return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }

  //---------die dump function----------
  function dd($data)
  {
      die(var_dump($data));
  }

   //Booking Page code (beginning)
   <?php
   require 'includes/config.php';

   $name = $email = $date = $phone = $age = $tour = $message = '';
   $errors = [];


  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


  $name = e($_POST['name']);
  $email = e($_POST['email']);
  $tour = !empty($_POST['tour']) ? $_POST['tour'] : '';
  $phone = e($_POST['phone']);
  $date = e($_POST['date']);
  $age = e($_POST['age']);
  $message = e($_POST['message']);

  $errors['name'] = checkNameBooking($name);
  $errors['email'] = checkEmailBooking($email);
  $errors['tour'] = checkTourBooking($tour);
  $errors['date'] = checktimeBooking($date);
  $errors['age'] = checkAgeBooking($age);
```

Comment: You're probably using `require` or `include` on the same file twice somewhere. Try changing them all to `require_once` and `include_once`, and test again

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I tried that and then the code just runs for ages and gives me the following error  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /Applications.....I have looked thought and I am only including the functions once also its been working find for the past 2 months, very weird? Any other ideas?